# Newbie confused by Android's findViewById() functions?

Tags: android, eclipse

am very much a newbie when it comes to android development so bear with me. Im currently using Windows 8 / Eclipse.

My issue is, the `findViewById` function seems to have gone mad, although I could very well be using it wrongly.

The app was working fine, then I 'dropped' a few new `TextView`s on the page which seems to totally confuse it.

The  `findViewById` function now either finds the wrong control completely, or doesnt find anything at all (and will return null). I've checked my `activity_main.xml` file and the id's are still correct.

Can anyone help?

This is a typical example of my usage:

```
public void toggleButtonNetwork_Click(View v) {
  ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) this.findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonNetwork);//did work, now does not work!
}
```

The only insight I may add is that my R.java file looked like this when it was working:

```
...
    public static final class id {
      public static final int menu_settings=0x7f070004;
      public static final int textViewGPS=0x7f070003;
      public static final int textViewNetwork=0x7f070001;
      public static final int toggleButtonGPS=0x7f070002;
      public static final int toggleButtonNetwork=0x7f070000;
    }
...
```

and now looks like this (broken):

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int menu_settings=0x7f070006;
    public static final int textView1=0x7f070004;
    public static final int textView2=0x7f070005;
    public static final int textViewGPS=0x7f070002;
    public static final int textViewNetwork=0x7f070003;
    public static final int toggleButtonGPS=0x7f070000;
    public static final int toggleButtonNetwork=0x7f070001;
}
```

Comment: Have you cleaned your project?

Comment: Post your layout xml that you're inflating too. Is the `@+id/toggleButtonNetwork` present?

Comment: R.java is automatically generated.  You never need to look inside it - unless curious.  Android takes care of the plumbing.

Comment: @A--C Yes, that worked! Thanks very much. Im confused though, should I have to do that everytime I add a new control to the 'activity_view.xml'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a quite common problem. Try and invoke the `Project/Clean...` on your project. It sometimes happens that the automatic generating of the `R` classes goes wrong and this will force them to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 3):

Everthing is fine.

Always Just go to **project -> clean** 
And **than run** .
Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question.  I suspect that A--Cs comment is correct.

But, there is nothing to be confused about.  `findViewById` is really simple.

When you compile your app, the compiler generates R.java and adds a line for each view in your layout XMLs (and strings, drawables, colours etc - anything that is a "resource") and gives it a unique ID.

```
public static final int toggleButtonNetwork=0x7f070001;
```

The ID will change as you change your resources, but it doesn't matter.  When you use `findViewById`, you give it the "friendly name", in this case `R.id.toggleButtonNetwork`, which is compiled into `0x7f070001` since `public static final int toggleButtonNetwork` is a static constant.

When you inflate your view from XML, typically with setContentView, the view hierarchy of objects is built.  The id of each object is the id found in R.java.

`findViewById` returns a reference to the object, of type `View`, which you then cast to whatever type of View it is which is why you use

```
= (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonNetwork);
```